# Sinatra exec/system 'bundler exec'

Tags: ruby, shell, sinatra, bundler

I'm trying to throw together a quick Sinatra app to call some test ruby scripts that need their own Bundler env to run.

Form a method in my Sinatra app I want to run something like

```
system("cd /test_app/; bundle exec ruby some_file.rb")
```

This doesn't work due to the way that bundler sets up its environment. Is there a way to start a new shell session to execute my script so it works form Sinatra?

Or is there another way to do this? Basically my only requirement is that these scripts can be triggered from links on a webpage so some team members can fire off test processes.

Comment: Should like what I am trying, unsuccessfully. I have a Rails app that I want to call a custom ruby script from using that scripts bundle... but I keep getting the bundle of the Rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this snippet which cleans the bundler env nicely. - http://johnbintz.github.com/blog/2012/02/02/the-cleanest-bundler-env/

```
Bundler.with_sparkling_clean_env do
  system("cd /test_app; bundle --gemfile ./Gemfile exec ruby #{cmd}")
end

module Bundler
  class << self
    def with_sparkling_clean_env
      oenv = ENV.to_hash

      %w{BUNDLE_GEMFILE RUBYOPT GEM_HOME GIT_DIR GIT_WORK_TREE}.each { |key| ENV.delete(key) }

      yield

      ENV.replace(oenv)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
Dir.chdir "/test_app"
`bundle exec ruby some_file.rb`
```

I also needed to `rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p320` before i started sinatra to get the correct ruby. rvm doesn't like to be told to change itself in a ruby process. (Which makes sense!)

(With the back ticks instead of system() you get the output back so you can print it or whatnot.)

Comment: I have what sounds like the same problem but this does not work for me. See my comment to the question to read what I am trying exactly.

Comment: I got this working now but combining your cd trick with Bundler.with_clean_env do...

Comment: aha - you wanted your "own" bundle for your script and the rails app bundle for the app.

Comment: Exactly. I read the original question to mean that too, but I could be wrong. My only problem with this solution is that it is on the calling side. I have no way to a cmd-line ruby script to enforce it's own bundle.